# Visual Studio Code intellisense for import entire module

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code's intellisense works great out of the box for importing a single or multiple exports.

However, I want intellisense for importing entire module like so:

```
import * as MyModule from 'path/to/MyModule';
```

So when I start typing `MyM...`, I want intellisense to kick in, and suggest to import the entire module. Is there a setting or plugin for this?

Comment: Wops, misunderstood the question. If the question is about triggering intellisense for `* as MyModule`, I don't think there is any way for that, since `MyModule` is a custom identifier. Because it's a custom identifier, the editor has no clue about which was / is the real name of the module and where it is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the named exports are member of the default export so `import MyModule from 'path/to/MyModule'` may be an import suggestion already.

If you are the author of the module, just add a default export along with the named exports of your module:

```
export A;
export B;
export C;

export default { A, B, C };
```

If you are not the author and the module does not provide a default export, you can still wrap your module into a new module doing that for you:

```
import * as MyModule from 'path/to/MyModule';

export default MyModule;
```

One way or another, MyModule has to be defined for the intellisense to kick in...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't found this to be working - intellisense does not kick in for default exports either. Another drawback with the approach is that it doesn't work for types (they can't be default export).

Comment: I can't see why you wouldn't be able to default export a type, maybe it's related to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13626, but anyway that wasn't what was intended.
For the suggestions above I meant the intellisense will kick in after having typed `MyModule.` but maybe you meant suggestion of all the content of MyModule without specifying MyModule first?